# How to get the title of root li element

Tags: menus, list

I want to get all info of top level menu from childrens

```
<li class="l-nav-item dropdown"><button class="open-icon visible-xs fa fa-angle-down"></button><a href=" ">Home</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu l-nav-sublist">
              <li class="l-nav-subitem"><a href="">Home Style I</a></li>
              <li class="l-nav-subitem dropdown"><button class="open-icon visible-xs fa fa-angle-down"></button><a href="">Home Style II</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu l-nav-sublist">
                  <li class="l-nav-subitem"><a href="">Home Style I</a></li>
                  <li class="l-nav-subitem"><a href="">Home Style II</a></li>
                  <li class="l-nav-subitem"><a href="">Home Style Portfolio</a></li>
                  <li class="l-nav-subitem dropdown"><button class="open-icon visible-xs fa fa-angle-down"></button><a href="">Home Style II</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu l-nav-sublist">
                      <li class="l-nav-subitem"><a href="">Home Style I</a></li>
                      <li class="l-nav-subitem"><a href="">Home Style II</a></li>
                      <li class="l-nav-subitem"><a href="">Home Style Portfolio</a></li>
                      <li class="l-nav-subitem"><a href="">Subitem</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="l-nav-subitem"><a href="">One Page Home</a></li>
              <li class="l-nav-subitem"><a href="">Without Header</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

i want to output the li children elements based on their top level parent. I use a custom field that is called

```
$item->megamenu
```

this field is present only on the top li element. for example

```
 if($item->megamenu == 1 ) {
  do something
 }
```

but this isn't working on childrens so i need to have

```
 if($theparentitem->megamenu == 1) {

 }
```

where $theparentitem is the top parent of the $item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found other alternatives to do that

in the top of the walker i create a variable

```
private megamenu_state;
```

than in my walker

```
if($depth == 0){
  $this->megamenu_state = $item->megamenu;
}
```

so the variable will get the state of the top level.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, assuming you are using a walker to construct your menu. E.g. when customizing the `start_el()` method, the `$item` should be an object - somewhat - like the `$post` object.

In reverse that means, you have access to `post_parent` property. With that information you can retrieve the title with `get_the_title()` easily.

After your edit I see you want the top level parent. So `get_ancestors()` could be helpful to you, to get the top parent. `$item->ID` can be used as `$object_id` and `nav_menu_item` as `$object_type`. `get_ancestors()` returns an array. Use `array_reverse` on it to have the top level ancestors `ID` at index `0`.

Comment: this give empty array on most of them

Comment: I don't know your code, so it is hard to tell. But for top level items this is expected, as there are no ancestors of course. Anyway, I'm out for now. @Eddy